# Calling default add/delete method of Django admin from template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I need to add a functionality where any one can add a new image in my image application.

So i have given a Add Image application link in templates. This link should by default call Add method of Photo model in models.py which is

```
class Image(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

My html file looks like this

```
 <h3><a href="{% url photoapp.views.main %}">PhotoApp</a></h3>
            {% if user.is_staff %}
            <a href='{% url admin:index %}'>Admin</a>
            <a href="{% url admin:photoapp.add_image %}">Add Image</a>
           <a href="{% url photoapp.views.search %}">Search</a>
            {% endif %}
```

Here it shows me that

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'photoapp.add_image' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My project name is photo which contains photoapp

```
photo
    photoapp
        models.py
        views.py
    templates
        photo
            list.html
        admin
            base_site.html
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Please let me know how can i call default add model function from .html file

EDIT

Added url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^(\d+)/$', photo.photoapp.views.album),
 url(r'^(\d+)/(full|thumbnails|edit)/$', photo.photoapp.views.album),
 url(r'^update/$', photo.photoapp.views.update),
 url(r'^search/$', photo.photoapp.views.search),
 url(r'^image/(\d+)/$', photo.photoapp.views.image),
 url(r'', photo.photoapp.views.main),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: Which version of Django? Show us the urls of photoapp.

Comment: Do you have a url/view add_image ?

Comment: @Bibhas - Django 1.3

Updated above

Comment: @Aldarund -- No. I do not have that. I think it Add Image (Image is Model) would be default property of admin. Let me know if i am missing something

Comment: @user2098662 I think it's better if you update your question with the urls, instead of posting in comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app_name is photoapp and model name is Image.

To use Add Image application link of admin in templates, write a code

```
{% url admin:photoapp_image_add %}
```

It provide url - /photoapp/image/add/

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I always thought that we need to write appname.add_model to access add method.